# Persist spree product pictures after 'heroku restart'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, spree

I have a sample page I'm working on:

```
http://os-oven.herokuapp.com/
```

where I started uploading pictures for products. At some point during my trying things out, I had to run

```
heroku restart
```

which wiped out my pictures:

```
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161552+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/spree/products/1/small/Pumpkin_Pie_from_a_-real-_pumpkin__November_2007.jpg"):
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161554+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161555+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161573+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161576+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161578+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161579+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161581+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161582+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161584+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161585+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161586+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161588+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161591+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161593+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161594+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:576:in `process_client'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161596+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:670:in `worker_loop'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161597+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:525:in `spawn_missing_workers'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161598+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161600+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161601+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2015-01-08T14:13:39.161602+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

The pictures must have been saved locally, and when I restarted my app, it pulled the latest code from git.

**How do I persist product pictures in the database for spree?**

My thoughts:

1. Put them in something like s3. Downside to this is I would rather have a 'free-er' option for now. Plus, how would you configure spree to do this?
2. Get the files in version control. This may work, except I would need prod and dev to use the same db with the same file paths stored in the db.
3. Persist blobs to the db. I know this is probably not the most efficient way, but the data would always be available. Still would have to tweak the spree engine to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save picture on heroku.
Heroku has "Read-only Filesystem" https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem

For free you can use cloudinary.com or Amazon S3
Amazon S3 also free up to 5Gb. http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: Actually, Heroku hasn't used a read-only filesystem for a long time (since the Bamboo stack). Today (with Cedar or Cedar-14) you get an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), which lets you write data, but this data is lost when the dyno restarts. The solution is still to [use S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) or something similar. [This tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) is Rails-specific, which may be helpful to the OP.